# Calculating area of a circle in C and calling it in main script

Tags: c, function, geometry

I have the following code but it gives me a completely random answer. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.141

//function prototypes//
double get_h_area(double r);

int main()
{
    double r=5.5;
    printf("A=%d\n",get_h_area(r)); //prints the answer
    return 0 ;
}

double get_h_area(double r)
{
    return PI*r*r; //returns the answer
}
```

**But the result I get is:** `-618475291`

**The expected result is:** `95.03`

Comment: While printing use `%lf` instead of `%d` as `get_h_area()` returns `double` type not `int`.

Comment: @Achal You can also use `%f`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.141

//function prototypes//
double get_h_area(double r);

int main()
{
    double r = 5.5;
    printf("A=%lf\n", get_h_area(r)); //prints the answer
    return 0;
}
double get_h_area(double r)
{
    return PI * r * r; //returns the answer
}
```

As @Achal told you.